# What would happen if there was a fifth fundamental force?

Tags: cosmology, universe, interactions, beyond-the-standard-model

Preceding this question, as a student of physics, my knowledge of theoretical physics is somewhat limited.

So I came across this [article](http://www.livescience.com/17809-gravity.html), which posited what the universe would be like if three fundamental forces existed instead of four (a universe without gravity, to be more specific). Immediately, the question I thought of was, what would happen if a fifth fundamental force was introduced?

Given the fact that we could create a universe:

- Could we create a universe with a fifth fundamental force at all? Or is that much impossible with our current understanding of physics? If we could "create" such a force, what would that require (i.e. adding a particle, what kind of particle, etc.)?
- If it is possible, what sort of things would change? Would the universe be completely unrecognizable or could it be relatively similar?

Thanks so much and hopefully this falls under the scope of the community. If not, please let me know ASAP and I'll delete the question!

Comment: We can't create any universes... I can assure you, as of now we can't even create a rational system of taxation (yes, I am doing my taxes right now). :-) In general, one can always add a very weak perturbation to currently known physics without messing up the agreement between observations and theory, which means additional forces could exist, but we don't have any experimental evidence for them. Apart from that, you shouldn't take the number four religiously, it's the result of a very biased counting scheme. One could make it three or two or seven by changing the rules.

Comment: *"Given the fact that we could create a universe:"* - sigh... I don't think that is even *logically* possible regardless of one's knowledge of physics.  Nature, to be commanded, must be obeyed.

Comment: @CuriousOne just curious what sort of rules you're talking about exactly?

Comment: @Alfred Centauri thanks for the comment, what exactly do you mean by logical in this context?

Comment: Gravity is not a force: -1. Electromagnetic and weak force are one: -1.  Color force and electroweak are considered to be symmetry broken remnants themselves: -1. If we don't care that a force is actually a force and are looking at symmetry broken remnants as independent forces, then we can add +4 and +1 for nuclear strong force, +1 for van der Waals, +1 for Cooper pair forces, +1 for Bose Einstein Condensation etc.. You could dig up any small low temperature effective interaction in solids and call it "A FORCE!".

Comment: @CuriousOne thank you so much!! It looks like I have a decent amount of research to do!

Comment: More on [fifth force](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+fifth+force).

Comment: @Qmechanic thanks! I've never heard of it! Exciting!

Answer (score 2):

This is a very tough question, since you do not make any further assumptions about the force - most importantly its strength, sign, variation with distance and objects it acts upon.  In general, yes, the universe would probably look absolutely different and we would not be here to ask this question. Somebody or something *absolutely else* might.

Our understanding of Standard model has unified the electrostatic, weak and strong nuclear forces into one theory; work is underway to reconcile it with the gravity, though developing of such a theory may well take the next decades.

It may happen we will even recognize new kinds of forces in the theory, though they were not experimentally observed.

Comment: Yeah I'm curious about how one would go about making these sort of assumptions exactly? Could you plug these sort of things into an equation or group of equations?